# Restkit mapping complex nested array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, restkit, nsset

I am trying to use restkit to read/parse an xml feed. which contains a nested array of artists.  I can map other relationships but am unclear what I am to do with the artist relationship below.

My dataset looks like:

```
<JamBase_Data>
<Results_Title>Jersey City, NJ</Results_Title>
<event>
<event_id>1896611</event_id>
<artists>
    <artist>
        <artist_id>96929</artist_id>
        <artist_name>The Happy Problem</artist_name>
    </artist>
    <artist>
        <artist_id>29817</artist_id>
        <artist_name>Craig Greenberg</artist_name>
    </artist>
    </artists>
<event_date>1/9/2013</event_date>
<venue>
<venue_id>48553</venue_id>
<venue_name>The Cake Shop</venue_name>
<venue_city>New York</venue_city>
<venue_state>NY</venue_state>
<venue_zip>10002</venue_zip>
</venue>
<event_url>
http://www.jambase.com/Shows/Event.aspx?eventID=1896611
</event_url>
</event>
</JamBase_Data>
```

Mappings:

```
RKObjectMapping *eventMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Event class]];
RKObjectMapping *artistMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Artist class]];
RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];

[artistMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes: @"artist_name",@"artist_name", nil];
[venueMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes: @"venue_city",@"venue_city",@"venue_state",@"venue_state", @"venue_name", @"venue_name", nil];

[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:eventMapping forKeyPath:@"JamBase_Data.event"];


[eventMapping mapKeyPath:@"artists" toRelationship:@"artists" withMapping:artistMapping];
[eventMapping mapKeyPath:@"venue" toRelationship:@"venue" withMapping:venueMapping];
```

Venue.h

```
@interface Event : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *artists;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Venue *venue;
```

@end

Artist.h

```
@interface Artist : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *artist_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *artist_name;
```

I can get venue to map correctly, but cannot figure out how to get Artists to map.  Is there something i need to do to tell the object manager to make an  coming off of the event?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my first foray into iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

The Artists object you see in the XML translates to an NSArray. Now that contains objects of type Artists. Have you thought about it that way?

Comment: I expected Artists to map to NSSet *artists in Venue. but when i try to read it, I am not getting any elements filled.`